# How to set up a relative path I think?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am new to programing so if you need more detail please let me know.

I am using anaconda prompt for a lab exercise and I had to download data for this lab. It says to save it in the same place as the anaconda3 folder was downloaded so that I could use a reference path to get the data.
[image]
The problem I am running into is that when I copy and paste the command given to me which is

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data/gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')
```

it gives me the error no such file or directory.

Now I know that I can use an absolute path to get to the file a different way I am just curious where I should save the gapminder file so that this command given to me works.

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` will tell you where the script is running and then `..` from there has to contain `data` otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that path to work, the folder with the python file in it and the folder named "data" must be siblings inside the same parent folder.

```
some_parent_folder_name?
    anacoda_notebooks_or_something?
        your_notebook_file_name
    data
        gapminder.tsv
```

Comment: okay so when i downloaded anaconda i put it in my user profile under the name anaconda and when i downloaded the data file i put the entire data folder in the anaconda folder is that not correct?

Comment: Relative paths are based on the CWD, not where the Python file / Notebook file live.  Additionally, the statement made in this answer is categorically *not* true.  A py file and its data do not have to be in the same parent directory.

Comment: @S3DEV I said nothing of the sort. The question was "I am just curious where I should save the gapminder file so that this command given to me works." emphasis on "command GIVEN TO ME". My answer addresses the command given - in that case it must be structured as I said.

Comment: @zstegmil if the data file is in the same folder that your notebook is in, then it would need to be a single dot: './data/gapminder.tsv'